# Save Img though web browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scriptcam

I am using the plugin ScriptCam to basicly take a picture with the webcam. I want to save the img once the user clicks "snapshot to image". It can download via the web browser thats okay for now, the end goal is have the img download to a particular destination folder, i would like this to work without using any php.

My Code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="JavaScript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script language="JavaScript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>
        <script language="JavaScript" src="scriptcam.js"></script>
        <script language="JavaScript"> 
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#webcam").scriptcam({
                    showMicrophoneErrors:false,
                    onError:onError,
                    cornerRadius:20,
                    cornerColor:'e3e5e2',
                    onWebcamReady:onWebcamReady,
                    uploadImage:'upload.gif',
                    onPictureAsBase64:base64_tofield_and_image
                });
            });
            function base64_tofield() {
                $('#formfield').val($.scriptcam.getFrameAsBase64());
            };
            function base64_toimage() {
                $('#image').attr("src","data:image/png;base64,"+$.scriptcam.getFrameAsBase64());
            };
            function base64_tofield_and_image(b64) {
                $('#formfield').val(b64);
                $('#image').attr("src","data:image/png;base64,"+b64);
            };
            function changeCamera() {
                $.scriptcam.changeCamera($('#cameraNames').val());
            }
            function onError(errorId,errorMsg) {
                $( "#btn1" ).attr( "disabled", true );
                $( "#btn2" ).attr( "disabled", true );
                alert(errorMsg);
            }           
            function onWebcamReady(cameraNames,camera,microphoneNames,microphone,volume) {
                $.each(cameraNames, function(index, text) {
                    $('#cameraNames').append( $('<option></option>').val(index).html(text) )
                }); 
                $('#cameraNames').val(camera);
            }
        </script> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="width:330px;float:left;">
            <div id="webcam">
            </div>
            <div style="margin:5px;">
                <img src="webcamlogo.png" style="vertical-align:text-top"/>
                <select id="cameraNames" size="1" onChange="changeCamera()" style="width:245px;font-size:10px;height:25px;">
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="width:135px;float:left;">
            <p><button class="btn btn-small" id="btn2" onclick="base64_toimage()">Snapshot to image</button></p>
        </div>
        <div style="width:200px;float:left;">
            <p><img id="image" style="width:200px;height:153px;"/></p>
        </div>

        <a href="#" class="downloadAsImage hide" download>Download</a>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                html2canvas($('.main'), {
                    onrendered: function(canvas) {
            $('.downloadAsImage').attr('href', canvas.toDataURL()).removeClass('hide');
        }
    });
});
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am really having a hard time with this. the script at the bottom will save the whole page and when it does this the img isn't even saved to the page. I just want to save the img only that goes into the

```
<div style="width:200px;float:left;">
        <p><img id="image" style="width:200px;height:153px;"/></p>
    </div>
```